# Отправка GET-запроса с объектом json

Tags: php, curl, get

Подскажите как отправить GET запрос на RestAPI с json-ом.

$json = urlencode({"foo":"bar"});

$url = 'https://somePage/?'.$json;

file_get_contents($url);

Comment: - url_encode\base64

Comment: Пожалуйста, чуть по-конкретней. Использовать 2 сразу функции? Может ссылка есть?

Comment: ууу =) дополнили вопрос вы хорошо =) читайте про curl и описание конкретного апи =)

Comment: ну спасибо, что не читать про php.